# Extract data based on tag attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following input:

```
<tag1>
    <tag2 id="value">
        <tag3>
            text
        </tag3>
        <tag4>
            text
        </tag4>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

I would like to extract the text inside `tag3` if the input equals the value.

So far I am able to extract the text regardless of `value`

```
tree = ET.parse(inFile)
text_file = open('output.txt', "w")
for p in root.iter('tag3')
    text_file.write(p.text + "\n")
text_file.close()
```

But somehow I can't go up and find the value of the attribute in tag2.

Comment: I haven't tried on ET Parser but the Xpath equivalent is xpath('.//tag2[@id="Value"]/text()').extract()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = open('data.xml').read()
d = BeautifulSoup(data)
print d.find('tag3').getText()
```

Comment: I am able to do this. I want to `getText()` only if the attribute of `tag2` is equal "true".

Comment: if `d.find('tag2').attrs['id'] == 'true'` then go with code

Comment: I am getting "BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")" I have no idea why it picks first tag and then stops working :/

Comment: Arun one more thing please, it works only for first time. So if I have more tag2 inside tag1 it fails for some reason and doesn't do them ?

Comment: in BeautifulSoup another option is that find_all It will return list of tag2 tags. So you can do it in a loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144616/discussion-between-arun-and-tony-tannous).